# How to highlight all the values in Elasticsearch which matches the string

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

Below is the sample query to highlight the field all the field

```
resp = es.search(index="test", body={"from": 0, "size": 1000, "query": {"bool": {"must": {"query_string": {"query": "Pencil" + '*', "fields": ["name^24"]}}}}, "highlight": { "fields": { "*": {}}}})
```

I am getting the output like below at last

`{'highlight': {'name': ['<em>Pencil</em>']}}`

I have "Pencil" in so many places in title, description.. Is there any way to "*Pencil*" in all places while retrieving.

Basically where ever pencil is coming, I need to identify that, it kind of highlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have given match fields as `name` i.e, `"fields": ["name"]` your highlight will return only name field, if you want to highlight in all fields add `"require_field_match": false` in highlight query.

your highlight query has to be like below

```
"highlight" : {
    "require_field_match": false,
    "fields": {
      "*" : {}
    }
  }
```